# ¿Cómo aplicar form-group a form::select de laravel collective?

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código pero no me funciona el form-group:

```
{{ Form::select('stars', array('1' => '1 Estrella', '2' => '2 Estrella', '3' => '3 Estrella', '4' => '4 Estrella', '5' => '5 Estrella'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

¿Cómo debería escribir el código para que se muestre el formulario como deseo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opciones del select, en tu caso, el atributo 'class' debe ser el cuarto parámetro del select. Así que, en tu caso quedaría:

```
{{ Form::select('stars', array('1' => '1 Estrella', '2' => '2 Estrella', '3' => '3 Estrella', '4' => '4 Estrella', '5' => '5 Estrella'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, donde puedo ver esa documentación? en la Web ofical de laravel collective al menos con select no me aparece.

Comment: La función select está dentro de la clase FormBuilder (Illuminate\Html). Te dejo el enlace: https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L393

Comment: gracias nuevamente, tengo otra duda que no veo. Coloqué un valor inicial seleccionado, pero cuando despliego la lista me aparece un cero (0) en la lista, justo debajo de la palabra Provincia, como puedo quitarlo? {!! Form::select('provinces', ['Selected' => 'Provincia', $provinces], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

Comment: Igualmente me sale el cero con: {!! Form::select('province', ['placeholder' => 'Provincia', $provinces], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}